# Dynamic dropdown in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif, dropdownlist

Trying to created a searchable dynamic dropdown containing a list of all of our products for order processing at work.

It is searchable which is one of the main uses, but it only works for one of the cells.

So far have the formula:

```
=OFFSET(Validation!AQ$3,,,COUNTIF(Validation!AQ$3:AQ$135,"?*"))
```

This works for the first dropdown, but every other cell afterwards only gives the option that was picked in the previous cell.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some of your list in column AQ are numbers ?* are text and countif count text cells in the above formula

Comment: If your list contains number only use >0 instead of ?* but if you have both you have to combine both you can use countif (for number)+countif(for text) because the result number is the number of elements in the drop down list